# Name for these kinds of "sayings"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for certain themes for a project of mine and I would like to use sayings like "see no evil, hear no evil, speak no evil". However, I'm having trouble finding more good examples.

What I'm mainly looking for are short sayings that have popular imagery attached to them, such as the above saying and the three wise monkeys. So the saying should be short and sweet and have an image associated with it.

Is there a specific name for these kinds of sayings?

Comment: The most common word for such sayings is 'proverb'.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a specific name for the concept you describe.

*Webster's new dictionary of synonyms* has an entry for *saying* as the most general term, compared and contrasted to *saw, adage, proverb, maxim, motto, epigram, aphorism,* and *apothegm.* I will reproduce it below, but suffice it to say that none of them are exactly what you want: either they are too general or refer to something other than your precise concept.

As far as the 'three wise monkeys' saying, [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=laCwd7DBKoYC&lpg=PA144&dq=three%20wise%20monkeys&pg=PA144#v=onepage&q=three%20wise%20monkeys&f=false) on folkloristics simply calls it a proverb. The [Wikipedia article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_wise_monkeys) introduces the very nice name *pictorial maxim* for the monkeys themselves, and says that this pictorial maxim 'embodies the proverbial principle "see no evil, hear no evil, speak no evil" '. There is a reference to an article (Wolfgang Mieder. 1981. "The Proverbial Three Wise Monkeys," Midwestern Journal of Language and Folklore, vol. 7, pp. 5-38), but I haven't been able to access it. In the book *Proverbs: A Handbook,* the same author says that

> For some proverbs and proverbial expressions like “Pandora’s box,” “The pitcher goes to the well so often until at last it breaks,” and “Hear no evil, see no evil, speak no evil” and the figures of the three monkeys attached to it, art historians, folklorists, and paremiologists have assembled various types of iconographic representations that span several centuries. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=rfWFu5C-tL0C&lpg=PA150&dq=%22For%20some%20proverbs%20and%20proverbial%20expressions%20like%22&pg=PA150#v=onepage&q=%22For%20some%20proverbs%20and%20proverbial%20expressions%20like%22&f=false)

The fact that these scholarly sources do not use any term more specific than a *proverb* to describe “Hear no evil, see no evil, speak no evil” suggests that there is probably no more specific name for the concept you are interested in.

Here is the entry from *Webster's new dictionary of synonyms*:

> **saying, saw, adage, proverb, maxim, motto, epigram, aphorism, apothegm** can all denote a sententious expression of a general truth. A **saying** is a brief current or habitual expression that may be anonymous, traditional, or attributable to a specific source <the *saying* is true, "The empty vessel makes the greatest sound"—*Shak.*> A **saw** is an oft-repeated and usually traditional or old saying <full of wise *saws* and modern instances—*Shak.*> <the old *saw* that ignorance is bliss—*M. W. Childs*> An **adage** is a saying given credit by long use and general acceptance <if there is verity in wine, according to the old *adage*—*Thackeray*> <there's an *adage* to the effect that a good horse eventually comes back to his best form—*Audax Minor*> A **proverb** is an adage couched, usually, in homely and vividly concrete or figurative phrase <accused (in the phrase of a homely *proverb*) of being "penny-wise and pound-foolish"—*Spectator*> <we hear, that we may speak. The Arabian *proverb* says, "A fig tree, looking on a fig tree, becometh fruitful"—*Emerson*> A **maxim** offers a general truth, fundamental principle, or rule of conduct often in the form of a proverb <the difference between principles as universal laws, and *maxims* of conduct as prudential rules—*Robinson*> <we have reversed the wise *maxim* of Theodore Roosevelt: "Speak softly and carry a big stick"—*Warburg*> A **motto** is usually a maxim or moral aphorism adopted by a person, a society, or an institution as a guiding principle or as a statement of an aim or ideal <William of Wykeham's old *motto* that "Manners makyth Man"—*Quiller-Couch*> <he adopted the maxim, "Napoleon is always right," in addition to his private *motto* of "I will work harder"—*George Orwell*> The last three terms, *epigram, aphorism,* and *apothegm,* commonly imply known authorship and a conscious literary quality. An **epigram** gets its effectiveness from its terseness and a witty turn of phrase; it characteristically presents a paradox or a cleverly pointed antithesis <what is an *epigram*? A dwarfish whole, its body brevity, and wit its soul—*Coleridge*> An **aphorism** is a pithy epigram that requires some thought <when Mark Twain utters such characteristic *aphorisms* as "Heaven for climate, hell for society"—*Brooks*> An **apothegm** is a sharply pointed and often startling aphorism such as Johnson's remark, "Patriotism is the last refuge of a scoundrel."